# Display symbolic expression in octave. Matrix multiplication as an expression and not as a result

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

I have hard time finding out how to display matrix multiplication as an expression, not as a result of an expression. The expression must be displayed in command line, not as a plot.

Lets say I have

```
syms m00 m01 m10 m11;
M = [m00 m01; m10 m11];
syms x0 x1;
X = [x0; x1];
```

I want to see the expression `M * X` as a symbolic expression. Something that will be displayed like:

```
| m00 m01 | * | x0 |
| m10 m11 |   | x1 |
```

And **will not** be displayed as a result of `M * X` evaluation:

```
| m00*x0 + m01*x1 |
| m10*x0 + m11*x1 |
```

I have read documentation on octave symbolic package. Can not seem to find the mechanics there. My thoughts are wrapped around converting expressions to latex,

```
m = latex(M)
x = latex(X)
```

Concatenating the result as a latex string, and somehow print the latex string in octave command line. No luck as of now.